# What's wrong with this database call?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

**-Issue Still Unresolved-**

I'm trying to call a database, put all the rows of a table in an array, pass that table to my JS as json data, and then use that data as parameters for a function.

When I run the script nothing happens. I don't get any errors in the console, the rest of the script loads normally. I'm pretty new to mySQL and PHP, what am I doing wrong here? I suspect that I goofed up the php somehow.

- XAMPP server, being tested on my desktop
- all linked files are in the same directory
- There are no visible errors displayed anywhere. As far as I can tell, the script doesn't even try to load the PHP to begin with, but also doesn't display an error in firebug's console

**Attempted**:

- Renaming the table without spaces
- placing the for loop inside the callback function
- amending php errors

Here's the updated JS I'm using:

```
    this.taskMenu = function()
    {
        var table = [];
        $.getJSON("taskMaster.php", {"table" : "firstlist"},
            function(data)
            {
                table.push(data);

                for(i=0; i<table.length; i++)
                {
                    var taskId = table[i].taskName.replace(/\s+/g,"") + i;
                    formatTask("interface",taskId,table[i].taskName,table[i].taskDescription,table[i].taskComplete);
                }

            });
     }
```

and here's the updated PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','On');
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "m3648y73");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());};
mysql_select_db("tasklistdb", $con);

$table = $_GET['table'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT taskName, taskId, taskDescription, taskComplete FROM `".$table."`");
$listTasks = array();

while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $listTasks[] = $row_user;

echo json_encode($listTasks);

mysql_close($con);
```

Am I linking to the DB correctly?

Comment: What do you see when you open taskMaster.php in your browser?

Comment: turn on reporting and errors add to the top of php page. error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','On'); Make sure this page gets called with proper parameters.

Comment: I just wanted to add that after you solve this, you should read about SQL injection. You are very vulnerable right now. Also, try using PDO instead of mysql_connect, it's the recommended way.

Comment: @Vatev I wish I'd thought of that. Nothing, taskMaster.php dispays nothing, so I assume I'm calling my database improperly?

Comment: what happens if you change the $_GET['table'] to $_POST['table'] ?  I think it needs to be post instead of get for starters.

Comment: If this script displays nothing that means the errors are hidden - see @FatalError's comment.

Comment: @user1542645 As FatalError suggests you really should go through your servers error log. If you only see a blank page that's the only way to find out what was wrong. You have a lot of very obvious parsing errors in your PHP (see for example Mike Brant's answer). eliminate those first before being worried about the database query.

Comment: adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','On');` to the top of my script doesn't do anything; I load the PHP in firefox and get a blank page with no console errors

Comment: @feeela as ctrahey states in Mike Brant's answer, table names *can* have spaces if they're back ticked and concatenated properly

Comment: I should note that I'm getting neither errors nor the results of `echo json_encode($listTasks);` when I load the PHP page in a browser; I get a blank page

Comment: I now suggest. you should remove few lines and check the output.. one by one... first loop+json, then query and then db connection.. see which one fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getJSON is asynchronous call. So before it could fetch values from PHP and execute the callback function, it moves to the for loop and here table is empty.

Solution: shift your for loop inside the callback function

Comment: I did this and it's not changing anything

Comment: Can you use firebug in Firefox browser and let us know what is the response you are getting from server?

Comment: I'm not sure where to look for this, but going through every panel in firebug, I didn't see my DB referenced

Comment: Under Net panel, if enabled, you shall see  a call to your page (taskMaster.php). When you click that url then you shall see different tabs.

Comment: I'm not getting anything under the net panel; do I have to have firephp hooked up?

Comment: If its not under Net Panel then it would be under Console. And if its under console panel only then it means that there is some error. And when you click the corresponding URL in console panel then it would show the error as well.

Comment: that's the thing though, there isn't - that's why this problem has become so frustrating for me.  There is no indication of an error in any of the panels; this is why I think there's a syntax error going on here. I've been going through the JS, PHP, and SQL looking for spelling/formatting errors and can't find any, so I'm at a loss. I appreciate your support so far, by the way, along with everyone else. This is all new to me and I'm starting to feel pretty lost.

Comment: Can you send me your skype id  at my gmail. And i could look into the problem via Team viewer?

Comment: You can also try to use fidler 2. It might give you much more details of your error as its tightly integrated to your IIS.

Comment: I don't have skype set up, but I appreciate your offer. After searching around, and encountering argument after argument against using PHP, I finally found a recommendation to learn and use rails, and as I already have a modicum of ruby experience I'm taking that route. I really appreciate all your help, and I'll be marking this answer as correct for posterity's sake.  Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semi colon on the line `$listTasks = array()` in the php file

Answer (score 2):

This happens because js-code after async request executed earlier than request itself is over. Try this:

```
this.taskMenu = function()
{
    var table = [];
    $.getJSON("taskMaster.php", {table : "first list"},
        function(data)
        {
            table.push(data);
            for(i=0; i<table.length; i++)
            {
                var taskId = table[i].taskName.replace(/\s+/g,"") + i;
                formatTask("interface",taskId,table[i].taskName,table[i].taskDescription,table[i].taskComplete);
             }
        });
}
```

Comment: You are logically correct, but if its fetched from cache by the browser then probably this might not happen all the time.

Comment: But still it's better to use more actions in callback, than hope for the cache.

Comment: I edited it in as you showed, but I'm still getting the same problem.  I will be leaving it in the callback though from now on (I understand the logic of it)

Answer (score 1):

Your table name can't be 'first list'

You can't have a space in a MySQL table name.

Also you should put put table in the JSON value in double-quotes like {"table":"table_name"}

Comment: Yes, you **can** have spaces in table names if you remember to properly quote the table identifiers (with back-tics) which the asker *is* doing.

Comment: Is this for sure? I googled that specific thing and the answers I got stated otherwise. If I really can't, than that's probably the issue

Comment: @ctrahey is correct.  You would have to always reference it within backticks.  This is generally bad practice though to name a table in that manner.

Comment: I need to be able to use the table names as visible strings at another part of the code. Could I achieve that using a table with a column of proper table names (no spaces or special characters), and a column of strings to display? Either way I need to solve the problem at hand, but I'll be keeping this in mind

Comment: I renamed the table just to make sure, but it's still not working